# Uncaught error: eventDate.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using `reactjs` & trying to find an particular `edate` from `eventDate` array of objects but getting error on following line:
`found = eventDate.find(el => el.edate === col.date)`

Just above the error line I console logged it to know that its accessible there and an array is printed, it also returns an `object` when I try `typeof` command.

My code snippet is as follows

```
const Calendar = () => {
    const { calendarRows, selectedDate, todayFormatted, daysShort, monthNames, firstDate, lastDate, getNextMonth, getPrevMonth } = useCalendar();

const eventDate = [{ "edate": '2-9-2022' }, { "edate": '3-9-2022' }, { "edate": '4-9-2022' }, { "edate": '5-9-2022' }];
let found;

return (
    <>
        <Grid >
            <Box  >
                <Box style={{ paddingLeft: '20px' }} className='currentMonth'>
                    <p> {`${monthNames[selectedDate.getMonth()]} ${selectedDate.getFullYear()}`}</p>
                </Box>
                <table className="table">
                    <thead style={{ background: '#D0F4FE' }}>
                        <tr style={{ background: '#D0F4FE', height: '40px', border: 'none' }}>
                            {daysShort.map(day => (
                                <th className='weekday' key={day}>{day}</th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            Object.values(calendarRows).map(cols => {
                                return <tr key={cols[0].date} style={{ height: '35px', width: '48px' }}>
                                    {cols.map(col => (
                                        col.classes === ''
                                            ? <td key={col.date} className='monthalldate'
                                                style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}  >
                                                
                                                {
                                                    
                                                    found = eventDate.find(el => el.edate === col.date)

                                                    (found !== undefined) ? <div className='dateborder'>
                                                        {col.value}
                                                    </div> :
                                                    <div>
                                                        {col.value}
                                                    </div>    
                                                }
                                                
                                            </td>
                                            : <td key={col.date}
                                                // onClick={() => dateClickHandler(col.date)}
                                                style={{ width: '9%', height: '9%' }}
                                            >{null}</td>
                                    ))}
                                </tr>
                            })
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Later I changed the code to below and it results in error:

```
[{ "edate": '2-9-2022' }, { "edate": '3-9-2022' }, { "edate": '4-9-2022' }, { "edate": '5-9-2022' }].find(el => {
                                                            if (el.edate) {
                                                                el.edate === col.date
                                                            } else {
                                                                return undefined
                                                            }
                                                        })
```

Resulting error:

`Uncaught TypeError: [{(intermediate value)},{(intermediate value)},{(intermediate value)},{(intermediate value)}].find(...) is not a function`

Error screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's the error? I think you'd have an error here: `(found = ...)(found != undefined)` since it'd trying to be call the `found =...` as a function, which it won't be.

Comment: Unrelated, but a collection of dates should probably be named something plural.

Comment: @DaveNewton Commentting line found = eventDate.find(el => el.edate === col.date) resolves the issue. If I just run eventDate.find(el => el.edate === col.date) after removing found then also it results in the error

Comment: Attaching error image for reference

Comment: I don't see how that's possible given the code; `eventDate` is in scope in the snippet provided. I'd check your assumptions regarding the code that's actually being executed, perhaps by logging it before the `return` or looking at the source in the debugger.

Comment: @DaveNewton Added the array inline but still resulted in array, added the code and resulting error => Uncaught TypeError: [{(intermediate value)},{(intermediate value)},{(intermediate value)},{(intermediate value)}].find(...) is not a function

Comment: Then something is horribly wrong; I can’t dupe this—it’s an array and it’s there ‍♂️ The function call is still an issue though.

Comment: @DaveNewton You seem to be right, commenting (found != undefined) does not result into an error. But what could be the reason ? I have handled it properly ? I have initialized found as false and If found is undefined then ideally it should go in else condition. May I missing something

Comment: You have an expression followed by parens; that’s a function call. “find” doesn’t return a function. (I see you’ve edited the code; can’t look at the moment on mobile.)

Comment: The issue is still the same; you're trying to call something non-callable. You *could* use a comma operator (or maybe a semicolon) but I'd probably extract the entire `find` chunk into an external function to avoid a bunch of code in the conditional render.